# Animation on a ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i make an animation on this ordered list?

I want the ordered list to open from the top to the bottom by useing ".hide" and ".show" but i cant get it to work. dose anyone know how to do with CSS or Javascript?

Looking for help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function loadul (name)
{
  var elem = document.getElementById(name);
  if(elem.style.display == "block")
  { 
      elem.style.display = "none";
      $("#work").click(function(){
        $(".test").hide(1000);
        });
  }
  else
  { 
      elem.style.display = "block";
      $("#work").click(function(){
        $(".test").show(1000);
        });
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<li id="work" OnClick="loadul('CTR')">List</li>
<ol class="test" id="CTR">
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your li external to your ol is technically invalid html.  An li is expected to belong to an ol, ul, or menu (or nav, i forget which)

Comment: Also if you want to show the lis one at a time, your logic doesn't reflect that, as `$(".test").show(1000);` selects them all and shows them.  To delay their show, you have to loop over them and show them at different times, or delay them until their previous li is shown.

Comment: You combine pure javascript events with jquery ... pick one

Comment: ^^^ That's true, this logic, as it is, is going to create multiple bindings and you have logical issues around that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you, you can change the transition animation in the sub-list class. I'm adding an removing the "show-list" and "hide-list" class just to do a toggle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.sub-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
</style>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

function loadul (name)
{
  var elem = $('#'+name);
  if(elem.hasClass('show-list')){
    elem.removeClass('show-list');
    elem.addClass('hide-list')
    elem.data('height', elem.outerHeight())
    elem.css('height', '0px')
  }else {
    elem.removeClass('hide-list');
    elem.addClass('show-list')
    elem.css('height', elem.data('height'))
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<li id="work" OnClick="loadul('CTR')">
    List
</li>
<ol class="sub-list show-list" id="CTR">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
 </ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for TY @Jose Rodriguez

Comment: is there a way to make the ordered list hidden in "hide-list"  but still get the animation. if i have more then one list there is a gap between the lists? @Jose

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean, but this only works for a specific list, because in the loadul method you're calling passing as a param the id of the specific list.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how I would structure your html and javascript. I've changed your external li to something that might make a little more sense. And since you've shown you are using jQuery i've used .each() in order to iterate through your li elements one at a time multiplying a delay based on their index. Here's a [Pen](https://codepen.io/DanStevens/pen/zmVeEL) example as well.

HTML:

```
<button id="work" OnClick="loadul('CTR')">List</button>
<ol class="test no-margin" id="CTR">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Javascript:

```
function loadul(name) {
  $("#" + name + " li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
      $(this)
        .delay(1000 * index)
        .hide(0);
    } else {
      $(this)
        .delay(1000 * index)
        .show(0);
    }
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
ol.no-margin {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make the ordered list hidden but still get the animation. so i dont get that gap between my lists?@D. Stevens

Comment: Updated my Pen but essentially a simple css rule should remove any unwanted gaps between lists. Hope thats what you're after.